# Reason for failed query plan executions in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, execution-plan, azure-sql-database, query-store

We are using Azure SQL Database and recently we have experienced a severe performance degradation on our production database. When looking into Regressed queries in Query Store to find out the probable culprit, I found a regressed query where there were a few hundred *failed* executions of its usual query plan:

[image]

I was not able to find any information on how to figure out what exactly went wrong, just that [an exception aborted the execution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/best-practice-with-the-query-store?view=sql-server-ver15#start-with-query-performance-troubleshooting). The problem went away on its own after a couple of minutes.

I queried the `sys.query_store_runtime_stats` catalog, but saw nothing useful there.

Is there a way to get to the actual failures? Could I set up these errors to be sent out to e.g. Log Analytics automatically (as we're in Azure)?

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, I suggest you to try to download the 15 days trial of software like SentryOne, Red-Gate, SolarWinds, Quest, IDERA and use that to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way I know to solve this is to set up Extended Events. Specifically you can capture the error_reported event. Use Causality Tracking along with batch/rpc starting and batch/rpc completed to capture every bit of data about what's happening with the queries. Be sure to use some good filtering because this could generate quite a lot of data.